# Union size smaller than total members

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure of the record size of a binary file.
How can the sizeof(union_data) be smaller than the two data structures within the union ?

E.g.

```
struct hdr
{
    unsigned short hdr;
    char     hdr_name  [90];
    char     hdr_add1  [90];
    char     hdr_add2  [90];

};

struct data_info
{

    unsigned short no;
    char     name            [90];
    char     addr1           [90];
    char     addr2           [90];
    char     amount             [120];
    char     verb      [25];

};

union
{

    struct box_info_data box_buff;
    struct hdr dhdr;
    struct data_info  dinfo;

} dhdr_rec, ddata_rec;
```

Comment: There's no `union_data` in your code. I assume you mean `sizeof(dhdr_rec)`? Also do you understand how a `union` works? Its size is at least equal to the size of its largest member, and all its members share that space so that only *one* of them can be "valid" at a time. Contrast that behavior with that of a `struct`, whose size is at least equal to the sum of the sizes of its constituent members.

Comment: It will be the size of the largest member, plus possibly some padding depending on the compiler and compile options.  Were you expecting it to be the sum of the sizes of the members?  If so, I don't think you understand how unions work.

Comment: At this point you have not shown anything to be wrong. What makes you think that *"sizeof(union_data) be smaller than the two data structures within the union"*? Give us something to work with here!

Comment: I'm curious: if you expected the size of the union to be the sum of the sizes of its members, then what were you expecting to be the difference between a union and a struct? I mean, what was your reason for choosing a union over a struct, if you were under the impression they both kept members separate?

Answer (score 3):

Googling a bit, (just looking for union c), you'll find in the first article that:

**A union is a special data type available in C that enables you to store different data types in the same memory location.**

So, your union will use as much memory as the biggest of the three struct that you've inside it, NOT the sum of all three.

More info can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm)

Comment: It will use *at least* that much memory. It may use more if padding is required.

Comment: @KeithThompson, agree totally, depending on compiler, and compiler options, it may add some padding. Still, IMHO, irrelevant to the question and could only lead to more misunderstanding. And, after all, in a world with computers with gigabytes of RAM, why bother him with a few bytes? Let him learn first things first... again, just my opinion :)